# why http2 use prioritization over stream instead of requests?

Tags: http2

The concepts of "stream, connection, message, and frame" constitute the main design of http2. And what confuses me is the idea of stream.

At first, the stream idea seems to me only as a virtual description of the flow of frames. But then I find the priority of http2 is aimed at streams instead of messages/requests. And why is that, I think the applications both client and server sides care more about and directly control the requests or messages, not which stream these messages reside in.

Plese refer to "stream prioritization":
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/http2#design_and_technical_goals

Comment: ***I find the priority of http2 is aimed at streams*** Please provide some resources/links to support this.

Comment: @kiner_shah done in the question

Comment: @IMSoP in the link I have posted, multiple messages' frames share one stream.

Comment: @IMSoP oh, yes, then that makes sense. Thanks very much!

Comment: Comments expanded into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stream in HTTP/2 corresponds to all the frames which make up a request and its corresponding response, so is the natural place to handle priority and flow control. The sentences "the response for this request should have high priority" and "the stream for this request and its response should have high priority" are equivalent.

There is a mention in the document you quote of a stream carrying "one or more messages", but I think that's just sloppy language in that document. If you look at [section 8.1 of the spec](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#rfc.section.8.1) it says "A client sends an HTTP request on a new stream" and "An HTTP request/response exchange fully consumes a single stream."

There can be other *frames* in that stream, such as PUSH_PROMISE, but those aren't actual requests and responses; the response data for a server push is sent on a new stream, which can then be given a different priority.

Comment: thanks, I think I have understood the basic ideas of H2